# Image of a endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $E$ be the vector space of functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which are $C^{\infty}$ et $u$ the endomorphism such that $u(f)=f'-af$. What is the image of $u^n$ ? I think that it's $E$ but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: $u^n$ is surjective if and only if $u$ is surjective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking whether the differential equation
$$
f'-af=g
$$
has a solution for every $C^\infty$ function $g$. Since this is a linear differential equation of the first order, the solution can be even written explicitly.

If $u$ is surjective, then so is each of its powers.

Multiply both sides by $e^{-ax}$:
$$
e^{-ax}f'(x)-ae^{-ax}f(x)=e^{-ax}g(x)
$$
The left hand side is the derivative of $h(x)=e^{-ax}f(x)$, so we get
$$
e^{-ax}f(x)=\int e^{-ax}g(x)\,dx
$$
and so
$$
f(x)=e^{ax}\int e^{-ax}g(x)\,dx
$$
(where the integral at the right-hand side denotes any antiderivative).

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Thanks!